# Windows Service not functioning

Tags: c#, service

I hope anybody can help me.

I have a small app that runs on the PC with admin privliges. that uses this same code, and it works 100%

now i need to have this setup as a service, and eventhough i have managed to convert it to a service, i get it to install successfully. but it never fires off.

This is the first service that i have written and im not sure if i made some huge mistakes along the way as im not sure how to debug them as every launch says i need to install it first.

The service has to monitor a specific process, notepad for testing. and if it finds it open wait 10 seconds and look for it again. if it finds it again it has to kill the process. this entire process has to happen every 5 to 10 minutes.

the code i use for this is. the service has two timers on it timer1 and timer 2

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace testservice
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 10000;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            timer2.Stop();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            Checking();
        }
        private void Checking()
        {
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            if (pname.Length == 0)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1.Interval = 10000;
                timer1.Start();
                GC.Collect();

            }
                //MessageBox.Show("nothing");
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                timer1.Interval = 10000;
                timer2.Stop();
                timer2.Interval = 10000;
                timer2.Start();
                GC.Collect();
            }
                //MessageBox.Show("run");
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            if (pname.Length == 0)
            {
                timer2.Stop();
                timer1.Interval = 10000;
                timer1.Start();
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("nothing");
            else
            {
                foreach(var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad"))
                {
                    process.Kill();
                }
                timer1.Interval = 10000;
                timer1.Start();
                System.GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why would this work as an app but not a service?

Comment: you might need to run a service under the administrator account, also you not show code where timers are created (might miss to add  `Timer.AutoReset = true`), if it worked in desktop (probably event has been hooked up like a `Timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent`)

Comment: What kind of timer is `timer1`?  Where is it declared?

Comment: timer 1 is a timer that was dragged on through designer, if this is incorrect how do i fix it?,

Comment: I have managed to resolve this by rewriting the entire thing. using system.timers.timer, and only using 1 instead of two. having it scan once and updating a internal value, if the value is changed it kills the process. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

What i ended up doing was the following, it still might not be the correct way but it does work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace AveryMonitor
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private  System.Timers.Timer timer1;

        private static int check;

        protected override void  OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            this.timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer(15000);

            this.timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
            this.timer1.Start();

        }
        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            if (pname.Length == 0)
            {
                check = 0;
            }
            //MessageBox.Show("nothing");
            else
            {
                if (check == 1)
                {

                    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad"))
                    {
                        process.Kill();
                    }
                    check = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            timer1.Stop();

            timer1.Enabled = false;

        }
    }
}
```